# How to reduce the amount of time for CSV file creation from an external API

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a script in ruby that makes calls to an external API and uses the responses gotten to compile a CSV file. The script actually works properly as the files get to be generated but it actually takes too long to generate. The auth token from the API lasts for just 2 hours and so far the script runs for more than that.

**Any help to figure out a better way to think about the generation of the CSV file is very appreciated.**

So the way the script works presently is something like;

1. make a get request to a particular resource. E.g /books.
2. Say each book contains attributes like book_id, author_id, publisher_id, e.t.c.
3. loop through books, making new requests to get information using the related_book_id, author_id, publisher_id.
4. Finally, use this information to create the CSV file.

Books contain over 13,000 records. So for each record, I'm presently making a call to fetch;
1. related book by related_book_id
2. author by author_id
3. publisher by publisher_id

The meat of what is been done can be seen below;

```rb
def fetch_all_books
  # API call to fetch all books in batches
  yield books
end

def generate_csv
  fetch_all_books do |books|
    CSV.open("book_info.csv", "wb") do |csv|
      csv << BOOK_CSV_HEADER
      books.each do |book_details, index|
        related_book_id = book_details['related_book_id']
        author_id = book_details['author_id']
        publisher_id = book_details['publisher_id']

        related_book = get_book_details(related_book_id)
        author = get_author_details(author_id)
        publisher = get_publisher_details(publisher_id)

        row = BOOK_CSV_HEADER.map do |cell|
          # get values for a row using the result above
        end

        csv << row
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Presently, the script runs in over 2 hours, which the token from the API expires in 2 hours from generation.
I expect the script to run in less time than 2 hours. Maybe in much lesser time.

Comment: There's probabless less publisher than books, maybe you can cache the publishers in order to make get_publisher_details function faster. That should reduce the time a little. For the `row = BOOK_CSV_HEADER.map` I'm pretty sure you can statically generate it instead of using map. Also, try to reduce the amount of time you call CSV.open, disk operation are slow.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the main bottleneck is fetching book data sequentially. The following might speed it up.

1. Fetch all books in batches sequentially from `/books` and store them (memory / file / database)
2. For each book, trigger an asynchronous task to fetch it (multithreaded / separate worker process (eg. Sidekiq)). Store fetched results for each book.
3. When all tasks are complete, generate the CSV from stored book data.